# Using FileSystemObject to Export VBScript Code to Text File

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, filesystemobject

I am looking to replace the `MsgBox oXMLHttp.responseText` part of the below code with code that exports the results to a text file.  I have checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198810/creating-and-writing-lines-to-a-file) and found the following code:

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

```
' How to write file
outFile="c:\test\autorun.inf"
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)
objFile.Write "test string" & vbCrLf
objFile.Close
```

However, I have no idea how to actually implement this.  Is the outFile the location and name of the file to be created?  I believe it is.  But then what is the purpose of `objFile.Write "test string" & vbCrLf`?  My main question is:  What am I meant to be telling the created FileSystemObject to process based on the code below?

```
Dim request, oXMLHttp, url
    url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx"

    request = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" & _
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & _
    "<soap:Body>" & _
    "<CheckPhoneNumbers xmlns=""http://ws.cdyne.com/PhoneVerify/query"">" & _
    "<PhoneNumbers>" & _
    "<string >1</string>" & _
    "<string >2</string>" & _
    "<string >3</string>" & _
    "<string >4</string>" & _
    "<string >5</string>" & _
    "<string >6</string>" & _
    "<string >7</string>" & _
    "<string >8</string>" & _
    "<string >9</string>" & _
    "<string >10</string>" & _
    "</PhoneNumbers>" & _ 
    "<LicenseKey>Key</LicenseKey>" & _
    "</CheckPhoneNumbers>" & _
    "</soap:Body>" & _
    "</soap:Envelope>"

    Set oXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    oXMLHttp.open "POST", url, False
    oXMLHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    oXMLHttp.send request
    response = oXMLHttp.responseText

    MsgBox oXMLHttp.responseText
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

   ```
   Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   ```
2. Use it to create a [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object representing the file you want to create (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for the `CreateTextFile` function):

   ```
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\yourfile.txt", True)
   ```
3. Use the `TextStream` object (`objFile`) to write text to your new file:

   ```
   objFile.Write "some text"
   ```

   In your case, it looks like you'll want to write the HTTP response:

   ```
   objFile.Write oXMLHttp.responseText
   ```
4. Close your file:

   ```
   objFile.Close
   ```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and thanks for taking the time to break down how the code works.