# How to create text file and write to it in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have the following script which locates all access files on a machine:

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'mdb' OR Extension = 'ldb'")

For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name
Next
```

I'm very amateur when it comes to vbscript.  Instead of Echoing to a dialog box, how do I have the script write each line out to a text file called "Results.txt"?

Also, as a bonus, how do I include the date modified of each Access file?

Comment: Related (or possibly duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198810/creating-and-writing-lines-to-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Google search like `"vbscript create and write to text file"` will give you ocean of information on how to tackle this. Anyway here is simplest one to give you kick start.

```
'~ Create a FileSystemObject
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'~ Provide file path
outFile="YouFolderPath\Results.txt"

'~ Setting up file to write
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile,True)


strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from CIM_DataFile Where Extension = 'mdb' OR Extension = 'ldb'")

For Each obj_File in colFiles
    'Wscript.Echo objFile.Name  'Commented out

    '~ Write to file
    objFile.WriteLine obj_File.Name
Next

'~ Close the file
objFile.Close
```

Comment: I tried using it, but I got an error "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objFile.WriteLine'"  Any ideas how to fix it?  Did it work on your machine?

Comment: yes, it does work on my machine. What is the value you are giving to `outFile' ?

Comment: Try the updated code. I've changed from `objFile` to `obj_File` for `For Each` loop.

Comment: Cha Ching!  That fixed it.  Thank you for your help.  rep +1

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are looking for. In this part: ("C:\test.txt" ,8 , True), the first parameter is the path to the file. The second parameter is the iomode option. There are three options for the second parameter, 1 means for reading, 2 means for writing, and 8 means for appending. The third parameter is a boolean, true means a new file can be created if it doesn't exist. False means a new file cannot be created.

```
Dim FSO
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set OutPutFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\test.txt" ,8 , True)
OutPutFile.WriteLine("Writing text to a file")

Set FSO= Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the FileSystemObject's .[CreateTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method to create a text file. Study the documentation/sample carefully.

A [CIM_DataFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387236%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a `.LastAccess` property.