# How can I add a line between output text?

Tags: vbscript

The next title will replace the previous title on the same line. As a result, only the last one of the titles will finally remain in the text file.

My following VBScript will find a number of update titles (="Title" in the script). Each "Title" will be shown in the output file "c:\Testing\testing.txt". One title will be shown on the first line at a time. The command "Next" will bring up the next title, which will be shown on the same line when the previous title disappears. Simply put, the next title will replace the previous title on the first line. As a result, only the last one of the titles will finally remain in the file. Is it possible to add an empty line between two titles, so that all titles will be shown in the file?

```
Set Job = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set Tool = Job.CreateupdateSearcher() 
Set Result = Tool.Search("IsInstalled=0 and IsHidden=0")
For Number = 0 To Result.Updates.Count-1
    Set Title = Result.Updates.Item(Number)

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    outFile = "c:\Testing\testing.txt"
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)
    objFile.Write Title & vbCrLf 
    objFile.Close
Next
```

I want the titles shown on different lines rather than on the same line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create text file and write to it in vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045891/how-to-create-text-file-and-write-to-it-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that both **OpenTextFile** and **8, True** are not necessary in the following script, which works at my end.

```
Set Job = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set Tool = Job.CreateupdateSearcher() 
Set Result = Tool.Search("IsInstalled=0 and IsHidden=0")
Set X = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Z = X.CreateTextFile("Updates_found.txt")

For Number = 0 To Result.Updates.Count-1
Set Title = Result.Updates.Item(Number)
Z.Writeline Title
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Set objFSO  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\Testing\testing.txt", True)  'True = overwrite existing file
objFile.Close
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Testing\testing.txt", 8)       '8 = For Appending
objFile.WriteLine ("Title")
objFile.WriteLine ("Title2")
objFile.Close
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ flipdascript, an error arose when I ran it. The error is on this line `Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(""c:\Testing\testing.txt", 8)`. Windows Script Host said "**Line: 9. Char: 37. Error: Expected ')'. Code: 800A03EE. Source: Microsoft VBScript compilation error.**"

Comment: @MatthewWai In that line you are escaping`"` with another `"`. Just remove one `"` to avoid that error

Comment: @ Gurman, Done as you said, but another error arose on the same line. Windows Script Host said "**Line: 9. Char: 1. Error: Permission denied. Code: 800A0046. Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error**".

Comment: @MatthewWai That's because the 2nd statement already opened the file, so the 3rd statement can't open it again. Remove the `CreateTextFile` line from the code (as it would still truncate the file) and change the `OpenTextFile` statement to `Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Testing\testing.txt", 8, True)`. That will create the file if it's missing and open it for appending.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! It works now. One more question: how can I change the output folder **c:\Testing\** to the folder containing the VBScript file?

Comment: Do you mean replacing "c:\Testing" with "ScriptFullName"?

Comment: *\*sigh\** It never ceases to amaze me how answers with obviously broken code can still attract upvotes ...

Comment: @MatthewWai Use the `BuildPath` method for constructing a full path from the value of `WScript.ScriptFullName' and the filename.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what BuildPath is. Can you simply change the script in the answer, so that "C:\Testing" will be changed to the parent folder?

Comment: I could. But since you're here to learn, I'll refer you to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//z0z2z1zt%28v%3dvs.85%29) instead.

Comment: Then I suggest you hire someone to do the work for you. Here on SO we're willing to help, but we still do expect *you* to do the legwork.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and encouragement. I found the answer at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16145760/7397743) The "CurrentDirectory" method was used there.

Comment: @MatthewWai `CurrentDirectory` is the current working directory, which is not necessarily the same directory as the location of the script.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the script will only be run in its parent folder, so `CurrentDirectory` will do the job.

Comment: Sorry for that one extra " and thanks for correcting it

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote, which was replaced with a downvote. I wonder why.

Comment: @MatthewWai One of the downvotes on the answer is from me, because the code in it is still broken. And you shouldn't upvote (or accept) answers that are factually incorrect.

Comment: code corrected. Sorry for that...I think I'll never post anything again while in a hurry ;)