# VBS Writing to Text File

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I want to use VB script to write to a text file and have tried using:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Users\Internet\test1.txt","This is new text to be added",True)
```

I get error -

```
 "Cannot use parenthesis when calling a sub".
```

If I remove the parenthesis, I get error  -

```
Object required: 'My'
```

Have searched the help forums without luck.
I'm using windows vista. could I be missing some libraries or such ?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: VB.NET and VBScript are two very different things.  The code you have shown is VB.NET.  If you want to use VBScript then you need to write VBScript code.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point me towards a text file writing example in VB Script?

Comment: Thanks again.  Found some VB Script file writing examples and am getting somewhere now.  Much appreciated.

Comment: use search and google : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198810/creating-and-writing-lines-to-a-file

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it using vbscript.
This is a simple script to create a text file and write to it

```
    Dim fso, objOutFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("Myfile.txt",True)
    objOutFile.WriteLine "Hello World"
```

You can modify it to create and write file to any other location. For writing to an existing file you need different method.

Comment: Globals, parentheses, and not using .WriteLine.

Comment: Parentheses? (cf https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/)