# Create Text File using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Update()

    Dim myFileSystemObject As FileSystemObject
    Dim myFile As Object

    Set myFileSystemObject = New FileSystemObject

    Set myFile = myFileSystemObject.CreateTextFile("C:\Error.txt")

    myFile.WriteLine "Error"

    myFile.Close
    Set myFileSystemObject = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am getting the Error below:

> Compiler Error: Expected : expression

Tried lot many things but not working

Comment: A simply search would have given you relevant answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198810/creating-and-writing-lines-to-a-file

Comment: in his code he wants to use Early Binding, while your link shows an example of late binding

Comment: you are using early binding, therefore you need to set reference to the **_Microsoft Scripting Runtime_** library

Comment: new to vba, could you please explain how can i set reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library

Comment: @PankajJaju - simple search was done, and the link you shared i have tried that code as well same error

Comment: @gaurav - it's in the VBA editor menus, Tools -> References... then put a checkmark next to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in the list. Now you can use F2 to look at the various objects and methods in that library.

Comment: cool thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it will create the object for you and you can add data to the file as you need and then save it.

```
Private Sub Update()

    Dim fSo As Object
    Dim myFile As Object


       Set fSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

       Set myFile = fSo.CreateTextFile("c:\sample.txt", True)

       myFile.WriteLine "Error"

    myFile.Close
    Set fSo = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: no problem, don't forget to mark solved it it helped you.

Comment: how can i do that, new to website.

Comment: You click the "tick" :)

Answer (score 3):

There is another way you can do it:

```
Dim hFile As Long

hFile = FreeFile

Open strFile For Output As #hFile

Print #hFile, "Line of text"

Close #hFile
```

This way you avoid needed to use the `FileSystemObject`.