# Emailing HTML file contents with VBS script

Tags: vbscript

How can I get this script to load the contents of a HTML file and send it as the email body.

I keep getting an error that says

> Line 8
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument
>
> Code: 800A0005

I have tried that and it works thanks.

> But when it reads the htm file the script breaks because there are more than one “ in the file.
>
> I am getting this error

`Line: 13
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objEmail.CreateMHTMLBody'
code: 800A01B6`

What can I do to fix it.

```
Dim fso

Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objEmail.From = "user@Example.com"
objEmail.Subject = "Test Email"


Const ForReading=1
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Email.htm",ForReading).ReadAll
objEmail.CreateMHTMLBody = BodyText

objEmail.AddAttachment "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\user\Desktop\address.txt", 1)
row = 0
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
line = file.Readline
dict.Add row, line
row = row + 1
objEmail.To = line

objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = _
    "127.0.0.1"
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objEmail.Send
Loop
```

Comment: You're using FSO being creating it. There are other issues. You can look at this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449184/sending-outlook-email-with-body-as-contents-of-a-text-file?rq=1) to see how to use FSO.

Answer (score 1):

- `Set` statement assigns an **object reference** to a variable or property;
- `ReadAll` method reads an entire *TextStream* file and returns the resulting **string**.

Hence, next code snippet should work:

```
Const ForReading=1
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
BodyText = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Email.htm",ForReading).ReadAll
' superabundant Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' superabundant Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\user\Desktop\address.txt", 1)
' …
'
objEmail.Subject = "Test Email"
objEmail.HtmlBody = BodyText
'…
```

Please read Paul R. Sadowski's article [VBScript To Send Email Using CDO](http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm). There is a hint how to send a webpage from a file on your machine using [`CreateMHTMLBody` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms527024(v=exchg.10).aspx) instead of setting `HTMLBody` property.