# How to read a file in VB script

Tags: vbscript

The following code is a vb script that converts text from user input into speech. I want text to be obtained from a txt file.

```
Dim msg, sapi
msg=InputBox("Hello", "hello")
Set sapi =CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak msg
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read and write into a file using VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142678/read-and-write-into-a-file-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Const ForReading = 1
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim f
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\MyTextFile.txt", ForReading)
Dim text
text = f.ReadAll
f.Close
```

Comment: please close the file.

Comment: I agree with Ekkehard.Horner. If you don't want to deal with closing open files, read the file like this: `Dim text : text = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.txt").ReadAll`.