# how to export xml from url (function) into a file in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, export, livelink

Before we were running on Windows XP and we were using LiveLink, everything was working fine.
We recently moved to Content Server and Windows 7.

There is a function from Opentext xml export guide that let you export XML from a URL. The vba code use to load this url and put it in MSXML2.DOMDocument60.

```
Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmldoc.Load (xmlURL)
```

Since the migration this doesn't work anymore. I changed the URL to the new server and read the new guide. When I type the url in IE8, I get the xml, but it isn't properly formated...There is 2 spaces before the xml declaration that cause problem and the - and + to hide/expand are seen as characters too. If I copy/paste in notepad++ and remove the 2 extra spaces and replace all "- <" by "  <", and then load this file in my Domdocument, everything works. 
Encoding is the right one UTF-8, I tried a few parameters that can be passed to the xmlexport function but nothing changed.

My plan is to export the xml into a temp text file from my URL and correct it so I can pass the right xml to my function that populates my DB. I searched for a way to do this but none worked so far. thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use VBscript to read a text file into a variable, then re-write the variable into another text file, minus the first two characters.

Here's a page where something similar is discussed:  [Read and write into a file using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142678/read-and-write-into-a-file-using-vbscript)

It might be something like:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
    ("c:\scripts\servers.txt", ForReading)

strText = objTextFile.ReadAll
objTextFile.Close

Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\scripts\servers2.txt", True)
objTextFile.Write (right(strText, len(strText)-2))
```

I haven't tested this, but it's essentially what you want to do.  I think.

Comment: Ty for the answer, I found a similar approach that doesn't require me to modify the text

Answer (score 0):

I use the function :

```
 Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
 Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
 ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
 ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
```

to save my web page into a doc.xml, then I load it in the DOMdoc

```
 xmldoc.Load (path_to_doc.xml)
```