# How to search and replace data in text file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a text file with data. And I would like to copy the text after `#NAME:,` and add some more text after that.

Original file:

```
#NAME:,Disco Ball
http://my.site.com/discoball.mp3
#NAME:,Lasers
http://my.site.com/lasers.mp3
```

New text file:

```
#NAME:,mp3-id="Disco Ball",Disco Ball
http://my.site.com/discoball.mp3
#NAME:,mp3-id="Lasers",Lasers
http://my.site.com/lasers.mp3
```

As you can see, I want to be able to copy the text after `#NAME:,` and then add it within the new text `mp3-id=" ",`

How can I go about doing this either in a batch file or VB script?

Comment: You must show us some efforts from you , so edit your question and post the code that you have been tried until now !

Answer (score 1):

If you decide on VBScript: Open the file and copy the contents to a string, replace the correct sections, and then write to the file.

[Read and write into a file using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142678/read-and-write-into-a-file-using-vbscript)

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36242413.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=:," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF /i "%%a"=="#NAME" ECHO(%%a:,mp3-id="%%b",%%b
 IF /i "%%a"=="http" ECHO(%%a:%%b
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36242413.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Simply read each line of the file and use `:,` as delims which means "both `:` and `,` are delimiters.

The lines therefore are assigned as (the part before the first sequence-of-delimiters) to %%a and (the remainder of the line) to `%%b` (this is the action of `tokens=1*`)

The `usebackq` tells `cmd` that the filename is quoted.

Therefore, `%%a` will acquire either `#NAME` or `http` and `%%b` the remainder of the line after the first delimiter-sequence, so test which is being used and `echo` out the appropriate replacement string.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept VBS, then you should be able to work with JScript as well.

The [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The JREPL.BAT solution makes a solution nearly trivial:

```
jrepl "(^#NAME:,)(.*)" "$1mp3-id=\q$2\q,$2" /x /f test2.txt /o -
```

Use CALL JREPL if you put the command within a batch script.

Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or use `jrepl /??` for paged output.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little tweak from the answer of ***Magoo***

You can drag and drop your file text at this batch to convert your data :

```
@Echo off
Set "filename=%1"
For %%i in (%filename%) Do (set outfile="%%~ni_converted%%~xi")
(
    For /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:," %%a in (%filename%) Do (
    If /i "%%a"=="#NAME" ECHO(%%a:,mp3-id="%%b",%%b
    If /i "%%a"=="http" ECHO(%%a:%%b
    )
)>%outfile%
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you..

**VBScript Code:**

```
filename = "C:\path\file.txt"
textToSearch= "#NAME:,"
attachText= "mp3-id="
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Set outputFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\path\output.txt", True) 
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  fileLine=f.ReadLine 
  if Instr(1,fileLine, textToSearch ) then
     reminingText=Replace(fileLine ,textToSearch , "")
     '#NAME:,mp3-id="Disco Ball",Disco Ball
     newLineText= textToSearch & attachText & chr(34) & reminingText & chr(34) & "," & reminingText
  else
     newLineText=fileLine
  End if
  outputFile.WriteLine(newLineText)   
Loop
outputFile.Close 
f.Close
```